# .NET CLI : dotnet pack command is not working in correct folder and when .csproj exists

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface

I need to create a NuGet package from one of my projects. So I have the following command in my code.

```
CommandUtility.runCommand($"cd {templateGitPath} && mkdir nupkgs");
CommandUtility.runCommand("dotnet pack --no-build --output nupkgs");
```

But it returns the following error although I have a .csproj file and I'm running the command in the right project folder.

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1003: Specify a project or solution file. The current working directory does not contain a project or solution file.
```

How can I fix this?

**[UPDATE]**
NuGet package has created in bin/Debug folder. But could find why it's not get created inside the nupkgs folder.

Comment: do you have csproj file?

Comment: @viveknuna yes I have

Comment: so are you running the command from the right location?

Comment: @viveknuna apparently yes, I'm in the right location as well

Comment: @viveknuna I wasn't in the right location. Although I have added the commands to change the folder, it hasn't changed. This folder change should happen between two drives. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the location as the @viveknuna has mentioned. If you get this kind of error probably check for the .csproj file or the location.

Comment: I am happy that it helped you

Answer (score 0):

I think the current directory where you are running this command does not have .csproj file.Add the .csproj file and then try to run command again

Comment: I have a .csproj file inside the folder